# Teams freezes when user clicks on "task/invoke" button

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

Our app supports task module.
It worked just fine but about a month ago we started to receive reports from our costumers that when they are trying to open a task module, teams app just freezes.

This is how i understand task module requests work, in 4 steps:

```
1. User clicks on the button with data {"msteams": {"type": "task/fetch"}}`,
2. Teams sends request with this data to the bot.
3. Bot handles the data.
4. Bot replies with the appropriate url to render.
```

So we tested what happens when we click on the *task/fetch* button.
First of all we saw an error in the teams console:

```
TaskModuleLaunchService: launchTaskModuleByInvoke failed: "could not find app definition for app 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" where *00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000* is out appID.
```

And we don't receive any requests from the teams on the bot's side. So basically we have an issue on the step #1.

Unfortunately, we couldn't reproduce this on our devices, using the same card with the exact same button.
How can we fix this? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps or any sample, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Hi Sayali. Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, as i mentioned in the question, there are no steps to reproduce at least we couldn't reproduce it, seems pretty random.

Comment: It looks like the issue with app Id. Could you please check the appid in json ? and Could you please share the manifest file, so that we can try to find the root cause?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Hi. This is our app ID 02ffb7cc-5fcd-4b31-bcbd-b24bbca74cc7 and here's the manifest https://ftp.s1z.info/manifest.json

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT Do you see anything strange in the manifest ?

Comment: @Oleksa- We are checking this manifest but not getting the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT What do you mean by it? Do you mean you can't reproduce the issue ? What should we do next ? thanks in advance.

Comment: yes,we could not reproduce the issue.We are checking this issue internally let you know once we get any updates.

Comment: Thank you, @Sayali-MSFT looking forward to get any info that could help us.

Comment: There is latest update for teams. Could you please update and check with latest version? Are all the users on same teams version?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thanks. We'll do. Which version we should expect on the updated devices?

Comment: @Oleksa-  Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.17004 (64-bit)-E

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT. We've updated the apps on devices where we had issues and it helped, We're not experiencing the issue anymore. Thanks a lot. Can you tell us what was it that was causing this issue?

Comment: @Oleksa-Could you please share the botId and timestamp so that we can investigate from our end let you know the root cause.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT here's our Bot Application ID fc70bbbe-91c4-4d8f-a9c9-a022068d5752 unfortunatelly i don't have timestamp of the issue.

Comment: @Oleska-Without timestamp it's not possible to find root cause.